# how to extract query result into sql file format using putty

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to extract select query result into SQL file format?

Below is the query :

```
Select * from shift_details where employee_number= '121' and work_date between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqldump and the --where Flag to add your Query

```
mysqldump -u <USERNAME> -p <DATABASE> shift_details  --where "employeenumber='18180' and work_date between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-05'" > shiftdetails.sql
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html for further reference